# Npm link and scoped packages

Tags: node.js, npm, npm-link, ln

When running `npm link` (as per the multiple vague blog posts on the subject) on a private scoped packed, I am getting an `E404` error.

This seems particularly odd considering the entire point of `npm link` is to sym-link local files. I do not understand why any request is being made.

Here are my commands;

```
$ cd /path/to/library
$ npm link
$ cd /path/to/my/project
$ npm link library
```

Which gives

```
npm ERR! code E404
npm ERR! 404 Not Found - GET https://registry.npmjs.org/library - Not found
npm ERR! 404 
npm ERR! 404  'library@*' is not in this registry.
```

Anyway, I don't want to link to `node_modules/library`, the actual library is `node_modules/@scope/library`, so I also tried (in the project folder)

```
$ npm link @scope/library
```

Which gives a similar error

```
npm ERR! code E404
npm ERR! 404 Not Found - GET https://registry.npmjs.org/@scope/library - Not found
npm ERR! 404 
npm ERR! 404  '@scope/library@*' is not in this registry.
```

The scoped library is hosted on an internal repository, not the global npmjs repository, but I still don't understand why this request is being made since I want to link the local library changes to my local project.

Also, is there anything fundamentally different between using `npm link` and using `ln -s` myself?

Answer (score 3):

So npm link relies on the details within the `package.json` in the folder you initially run `npm link`

Typing `npm -g list` will show that the library is linked using the name and version in the package.json

```
$ npm -g list
/home/user/.npm-global/lib
├── @scope/library-name-in-package-json@1.2.3 -> ./../../path/to/library
```

So the solution is simply to run the command with the name given in the global npm install list

```
$ npm link @scope/library-name-in-package-json
```